# Почему компилятор C# неявно преобразует double в int при приведении к пользовательскому типу?

Tags: c#

Почему возможно явного преобразование типа double в тип foo, хотя в моем типе foo определено только явное преобразование из типа int в тип foo?

Почему в моем случае тип double неявно преобразуется в тип int?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double doub = 15.7;
        Foo foo = (Foo)doub;
        Console.WriteLine(foo.value); //выводит 15
    }
}

struct Foo
{
    public int value;
    public static explicit operator Foo(int val)
    {
        return new Foo { value = val };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Такое поведение определено в [спецификации языка](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)  в разделе M. Conversions (M. Преобразования).
**Пункт M.2.8 User-defined explicit conversions**

> A user-defined explicit conversion consists of an optional standard
>   explicit conversion, followed by execution of a user-defined implicit
>   or explicit conversion operator, followed by another optional standard
>   explicit conversion. The exact rules for evaluating user-defined
>   explicit conversions are described in §User-defined explicit
>   conversion.

И в части пункта
**M.4.3 Evaluation of user-defined conversions** 
про это тоже говорится:

> ... Once a most specific user-defined conversion operator has been
>   identified, the actual execution of the user-defined conversion
>   involves up to three steps: First, if required, performing a standard
>   conversion from the source type to the operand type of the
>   user-defined or lifted conversion operator. Next, invoking the
>   user-defined or lifted conversion operator to perform the conversion.
>   Finally, if required, performing a standard conversion from the result
>   type of the user-defined or lifted conversion operator to the target
>   type. ...

Означает, что пользовательское явное преобразование может включать в себя три последовательных преобразований:

1. Необязательное стандартное явное преобразование. (Исходный тип к типу операнда, в нашем случае это `double` в `int`)
2. Пользовательское преобразование неявного или явного оператора.
3. Необязательное стандартное явное преобразование. (Тип результата из 2 пункта к конечному типу. В нашем случае отстуствует этот пункт).

Т.е. можно сказать, что происходит примерно так:

```
// Пользовательское явное преобразование.
Foo foo = (Foo)doub;
// Будет вот так.
Foo foo = (Foo)(int)doub;
```

Если глянуть в IL, то увидим там опкод [conv.i4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_i4(v=vs.110).aspx) перед вызовом пользовательского приведения.

```
IL_0000: ldc.r8 15.7
IL_0009: dup
IL_000a: conv.i4
IL_000b: call valuetype Foo Foo::op_Explicit(int32)
```

Т.е. все работает в соответствии со спецификацией.

Comment: мда, неприятная особенность....

Comment: Помню, попадалось мне поднобное у Эрика Липперта, там, вроде бы, описывалось почему так сделали.

Comment: может причины и были, но хуже этой особенности, только тип `dynamic`, нарушающий строгую типизацию языка. Хотя тоже в общем -то понятно зачем его сделали

Comment: с `dynamic` кстати тоже работает, только IL выглядит ужасно =)

Comment: @rdorn, идиотская особенность, я бы даже сказал. Тупо скопировали правило приведения из C++, только вот в C++ double в int имеет implicit conversion, в отличии от C#

Answer (score 5):

1. Если определить перегруженный вариант оператора приведения для нужного типа, то выбирается правильный вариант, и приведение выполняется как положено.
2. Если для нужного типа преобразование не определено, но определен хотябы один оператор приведения, то преобразование происходит молча из любого числового типа в любой числовой тип.

Важно, это наблюдается только с числовыми типами. `char` и другие встроенные типы, семантика которых не подразумевает число, как положено возвращают ошибку на этапе компиляции.

Чуть раньше ответили что это особенность, не очень приятно но факт. Будьте внимательны, таким способом вполне можно выстрелить себе в ногу.

В IL это выглядит так:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.r8      66 66 66 66 66 66 2F 40 //doub = 15.7
IL_000A:  stloc.0     // doub
IL_000B:  ldloc.0     // doub
IL_000C:  conv.i4     //преобразование в Int32
IL_000D:  call        UserQuery+Foo.op_Explicit//преобразование в Foo
```

Comment: Эх, не заметил и тоже написал про IL :)